# Convert current <a> into CodeIgniter "anchor"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the current code

```
<a href="http://localhost/dashboard.php">
  <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
  <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
</a>
```

I'm trying to convert it to the standard that code Igniter uses with the anchor tag. I'm assuming it would be similar to

```
<?= anchor('dashboard/index', 'Dashboard') ?>
```

But I'm not sure how to get the other tags and classes in there. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third parameter ,

`<?= anchor('dashboard/index', 'Dashboard','class="fa fa-dashbaord"') ?>`

for the span you can just add it directly on the second param

```
<?= anchor('dashboard/index', 
           '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
            <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>',
           'class="fa fa-dashbaord"') ?>
```

note: be carefull with the single qoutes and double qoutes.

[DOCUMENTATION](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 2):

### anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)

In your case:

```
anchor('dashboard/index', 'Dashboard',array('class' => 'fa fa-dashboard','id'=>'your_id','title'=>'Link_title'))
//You can add multiple attributes in an array.nice class by the way
```

[see documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: What about the span, and the class on the span?

Comment: Anchor creates a standard HTML anchor link based on your local site URL

Comment: Very nice answer Mr Moeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
echo anchor('dashboard/index', 'My News', 'title="News title"');
```

Orignal syntax is  :

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes);
```

Details are [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try it like this

```
$dashboard  =   '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>';
<?= anchor('dashboard/index', '$dashboard') ?>
```